# Cannot boot Windows after deleting Ubuntu partition and cannot boot from CD also.

Tags: grub2, bios, grubrescue

I have the problem of having the `unknown filesystem: rescue grub` screen come up.

I recently deleted the partition of my hard drive that had Ubuntu Studio on it in an effort to clear up more space on my computer. I also have Windows 7 installed on the computer. Also I cannot access the BIOS and there is no splash screen option for me to boot from CD. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Windows Recovery CD/Rescue CD to fix the Windows boot problem.

You should absolutely be able to enter BIOS or choose boot order with a keyboard shortcut -- look up your system manual. Worst case, if you unplug the hard drive and boot with a CD in, the computer will probably show you the CD's splash screen. Then you can reconnect the hard drive and boot the CD.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get access to windows 7 system just boot with your windows 7 DVD and perform a startup repair.

Here is a [step by step guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/)

A Operation system installation doesn't affect BIOS. Keep pressing F2 or DEL key to get access to BIOS. Consult yout hardware manual.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry I have a nice solution. you will need Windows Installation Disk or Windows Repair disk.

To Create Windows 7 Repair disk , Get any PC or laptop having Windows 7. On start search menu type "CREATE System REPAIR DISK", select option comes

You will be ask for a Blank DVD, Insert Disk and Burn It.
After making Repair disk Boot from DVD in your PC

You should see this on an installation menu. Click "Repair your computer" and you

Open the Command Prompt, then type

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

into the Command Prompt.

reboot your system now you will be able to load your Windows 7.